# Relative Links Not working on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

There is an issue I am facing in HTML page.

I have included a javascript code in that page due to which ActiveX warning message is thrown each time the HTML page is uploaded on local system.

To stop this warning being shown to the users, I have used MOTW (Mark of the Web) and included this code snippet at the top of the HTML Page:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost-->
```

This line of code prohibits the warning prompt message.

But now the relative URLs on the page have stopped working.

Please help me find me a solution so that neither the ActiveX warning arises nor the relative links on the page should stop working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dis you try using <!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->

Comment: @shiva already tried this. but still relative links won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The ActiveX warnings should only arise when you are accessing your site from the local file system, for security reasons. When you access it through a (local or remote) web server the warnings should be gone.

Can you not use Apache (included in [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/index.html)), or something similar, to serve your pages (even locally, through `http://localhost/`)?

Edit:

Alternatively, you could disable that particular security setting in Internet Explorer (which I assume you use, because you mention ActiveX). Or you could try a different browser: Firefox, for example, does not have these restrictions.

Comment: i'm afraid cannot use Apache.Is there any other way out?

Comment: You could disable that particular security setting in Internet Explorer (which I assume you use, because you mention ActiveX). Or you could try a different browser: Firefox, for example, does not have this restriction. These are solutions for **you** locally; is that enough? Do any other users access your pages locally (remotely should be no problem)?

Comment: We cannot make changes in IE settings.The application has around 100+ users.They access the pages locally.So,we are looking for a code solution so that Active X warning is removed the all the links function properly.

Comment: @user3114356 As far as I can tell, this isn't going to work then. When using the MotW, your site can no longer access the local file system (which is where relative URLs are pointing).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a `<base href="ENETERBASEURLHERE" />`